# Strange behaviour of imsave Python operator with jpg output format

Tags: python, image, matplotlib, save, jpeg

I encounter an enigmatic behaviour with the imsave operator of Python, seemigly bounded to the output file format. A little code to explain:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

array1 = np.array([[[255,255,255],[ 0 , 0 , 0 ]]],dtype = np.uint8)
plt.imsave('picture.jpg',array1) # a picture with 1 white pixel and 1 black pixel
array2 = plt.imread('picture.jpg')
```

print(array1) provides:

```
[[[255 255 255]
  [  0   0   0]]] => OK
```

print(array2) provides:

```
[[[254 254 254]
  [  3   3   3]]] => NOK
```

I do not understand the "loss of data".
I tried to save with png or tiff formats: no problem.
Does anybody know what is the origin of this behaviour?

Comment: jpg is a lossy format.

Comment: Thank you! I shall forward my investigation with the jpg algorithm to understand this loss.

Comment: `jpeg` is lossy and is able to compress images a lot. It trades image quality for image size. Many implementations allow setting a quality factor, with matplotlib this goes via `imsave(....jpg, ...., pil_kwargs={'quality':75})` ([docs](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/image-file-formats.html#jpeg)).  `jpeg` is meant for photos, where small errors can often get unnoticed.  For most matplotlib plots, the `png` format is preferred. `png` compresses without loss, and takes advantage of equally colored regions.